# spaCy - Most efficient way to sort entities by label

Tags: python, entity, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm using spaCy pipeline to extract all entities from articles. I need to save these entities on a variable depending on the label they have been tagged with. For now I have this solution, but I think this is not the most suitable one as I need to iterate over all the entities for each label:

```
nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_md")
text = # I upload my text here
doc = nlp(text)

personEntities = list(set([e.text for e in doc.ents if e.label_ == "PER"]))
locationEntities = list(set([e.text for e in doc.ents if e.label_ == "LOC"]))
organizationEntities = list(set([e.text for e in doc.ents if e.label_ == "ORG"]))
```

Is there a direct method in spaCy in order to get all the entities for each label or would I need to do `for ent in ents: if... elif... elif...` to achieve that?

Comment: Use `itertools` to `groupby` the entities.

Comment: Use a dictionary to group by entities, where the key is the entity type

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you expand a bit more on how you would use `groupby` for this?

Comment: Add `from itertools import *`. Then use `entities = {key: list(g) for key, g in groupby(doc.ents, lambda x: x.label_)}`. Later, you will be able to use it like `print(entities['DATE'])` etc.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That will only work if the labels are consecutive

Comment: @DanielMesejo No problem, we can sort them before, `entities = {key: list(g) for key, g in groupby(sorted(doc.ents, key=lambda x: x.label_), lambda x: x.label_)}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Agreed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using the `groupby` method from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import *
#...
entities = {key: list(g) for key, g in groupby(sorted(doc.ents, key=lambda x: x.label_), lambda x: x.label_)}
```

Or, if you need to only extract unique values:

```
entities = {key: list(set(map(lambda x: str(x), g))) for key, g in groupby(sorted(doc.ents, key=lambda x: x.label_), lambda x: x.label_)}
```

Then, you may print known entities using

```
print(entities['ORG'])
```

If you need to get unique occurrences of the entity *objects*, not just *strings*, you may use

```
import spacy
from itertools import *

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
s = "Hello, Mr. Wood! We are in New York. Mrs. Winston is not coming, John hasn't sent her any invite. They will meet in California next time. General Motors and Toyota are companies."
doc = nlp(s * 2)

entities = dict()
for key, g in groupby(sorted(doc.ents, key=lambda x: x.label_), lambda x: x.label_):
    seen = set()
    l = []
    for ent in list(g):
      if ent.text not in seen:
        seen.add(ent.text)
        l.append(ent)
    entities[key] = l
```

Output for `print(entities['GPE'][0].text)` is `New York` here.

Comment: How can I achieve to have the output of `entities['ORG']` as a list without duplicated elements? I tried to do the same I was doing before `list(set(entities['ORG']))` but it didn't seem to work

Comment: @Luiscri It should work, could you please show the output of `entities['ORG']`?

Comment: `print(entities['ORG']` returns this: `[Asociación Española de Fabricantes de Automóviles y Camiones, PSA, Ford, Renault, Unión Europea, UE, IDAE, Ejecutivo, IDAE, Instituto para la Diversificación, IDAE, Administración]`

Comment: `print(set(entities['ORG']))` returns this: `{Asociación Española de Fabricantes de Automóviles y Camiones, IDAE, IDAE, Instituto para la Diversificación, Ejecutivo, IDAE, UE, Ford, Administración, PSA, Unión Europea, Renault}`

Comment: Not sure but please also try `list(set(map(lambda x: str(x), entities['ORG']) ))`. However, the code was tested on a small sentence and it worked.

Comment: That's it, they weren't being saved as strings, so now with the map it worked. Could I solve this problem by changing your solution like `{key: list(str(g) for key, g...` ?

Comment: @Luiscri Yeah, `list(g)` => `list(set(map(lambda x: str(x), g)))`

Comment: Perfect, this looks great now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry for reviving this, but how could I get a list of unique entities sorted by its label? I mean, all ORG (i.e) entities comes first, then all PER ones... And that the list elements are still entities objects with its .text and .label_ values. I have been trying to get this for a while and I'm not able to

Comment: Just in case notification did not reach you @WiktorStribizew

Comment: How do you define a pair of duplicate entities?

Comment: By having the same .text and .label_ attributes @WiktorStribizew

Comment: Isn't that the same result we got with the second solution you posted? That's not exactly what I was asking. I meant: I want to get only a list with all the entities, as the one I get by doing doc.ents . However I need that the entities in this list are sorted by its label, i.e first appear all the entities with the LOC label, then all the entities with the PER label and then all the entities with the ORG one. Morever, I want that if two entities has the same text and label, they appear only once. I think It can be done in only one line as your first answers, but I'm not able to get it